# "--enable-gtk" for qemu configure gives me 'Install gtk3-devel' message. (on ubuntu 18.04, arm64 machine)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, qemu, gtk3

I've been using this command to configure qemu-5.1.0 on another machine (ubuntu 20.40, amd64)

> ../configure --target-list=aarch64-softmmu --enable-debug --enable-gtk
> --extra-ldflags="-Wl,--no-as-needed,--export-dynamic -ldl"

But when I did the same on a ubuntu 18.04 arm64 machine, it gave me this message.

```
ckim@n1sdp:~/prj/QEMU/qemu-5.1.0/build$ ../configureit

ERROR: User requested feature gtk
       configure was not able to find it.
       Install gtk3-devel
```

So I did

```
ckim@n1sdp:~/prj/QEMU/qemu-5.1.0/build$ sudo apt install gtk3-devel
sudo: unable to resolve host n1sdp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gtk3-devel
```

When I do `dpkg -l | grep gtk`, I get this list (all already installed ones):

```
ii  libcanberra-gtk3-0:arm64             0.30-5ubuntu1                       arm64        GTK+ 3.0 helper for playing widget event sounds with libcanberra
ii  libcanberra-gtk3-module:arm64        0.30-5ubuntu1                       arm64        translates GTK3 widgets signals to event sounds
ii  libgtk3-perl                         0.032-1                             all          Perl bindings for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets        1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.5            all          Python 3 GTK+ 3 widgets to run an aptdaemon client
```

and I used `sudo apt-cache search gtk3` and removed lines that don't contain 'dev' pattern. And it boils down to this list.

```
libavahi-ui-gtk3-dev - Development headers for the Avahi GTK+ User interface library
libcanberra-gtk-common-dev - simple interface for playing event sounds (GTK+ shared development files)
libcanberra-gtk3-dev - simple interface for playing event sounds (GTK+ 3 development files)
libdbusmenu-gtk3-dev - library for passing menus over DBus - GTK+ version developement files
golang-github-gotk3-gotk3-dev - Go bindings for GTK3
libappmenu-gtk3-parser-dev - GtkMenuShell to GMenuModel parser (GTK+3.0 development files)
libgarcon-gtk3-1-dev - Development files for garcon-gtk3
libghc-gtk3-dev - binding to the Gtk+ graphical user interface library
libgtk3.0-cil-dev - CLI binding for the GTK+ toolkit 3.0
libgwengui-gtk3-dev - Gwenhywfar GUI implementation for GTK3 (development files)
libindicate-gtk3-dev - library for raising indicators via DBus - GTK bindings development files
libspice-client-gtk-3.0-dev - GTK3 widget for SPICE clients (development files)
libunity-gtk3-parser-dev - GtkMenuShell to GMenuModel parser
libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-dev - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK+ 3 media library development)
libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-dev - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK+ 3 webview library development)
libwxgtk3.0-dev - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK+ development)
libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK+ 3 development)
libxfce4panel-2.0-dev - Xfce4 panel libraries (GTK3 variant)
python-wxgtk3.0-dev - Development files for wxPython
```

I know installing unnecessary package doesn't do any harm but which one should I install?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install libavahi-ui-gtk3-dev` solved it.

Comment: This worked by accident via further dependencies, you'd really need/want libgtk-3-dev (and probably for --enable-vte also libvte-2.91-dev)

Comment: When I do it now, it gives me "libgtk-3-dev is already the newest version (3.22.30-1ubuntu4). libgtk-3-dev set to manually installed." I think I've seen this message earlier. not quite sure, can't check now because it's already installed :) Thanks for the infomation.